# Breakpoints are not working in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtquick2

I have set my application to debug mode, even so the breakpoints is not working. I am using Qt Creator on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, I didn't install the GDB Debugger. 
a quick `pacman -S gdb` solved the issue